# Return to same view after starting workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I've created a custom action to start a workflow created with SharePoint Workflow Designer. When use the action, the workflow's initation form appears.

Problem is when I click "Start" in the initiation form, I'm redirected back to the lists default view. And not the view I activated the action from.

What can I do to make the workflow intitation form return to my current view, and not the lists default view?

Larsi

Comment: What workflow is it, custom or out of the box?

Comment: Custom (made from Workflow Designer in SD, not using VS)

Answer (score 2):

Appending the ReturnURL query string parameter to your URL should take care of it.

http://site/someurl.aspx?Source=http://site/sub-site/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, only I'm starting the workflows within EasyTabs from the list item menu. I have about a dozen views, so a tabbed presentation makes the most sense.  The content editor web part that houses EasyaTabs is on the default.aspx page of the subsite.  After a workflow finishes, I am sent to the default VIEW for the list:

//site/sub-site/Lists/list_name/allitems.aspx (or whatever is named as the default view)

Where I really want to be is

//site/sub-site/default.aspx

It happens that EasyTabs remembers which tab I was last on, so simply returning to the page is enough.

Options:

1. Redirect from default view (using a dummy view) - can't figure out how to make this work
2. use source parameter in url - can't find an opportunity to set this, was hoping I might be able to attach it to the Start button in infopath form, but no luck there.  Also nowhere to set it in List Item Menu action.

Does anyone know where in Sharepoint (what class, xml, etc) the behavior to return to default view is defined?

Comment: Looks like you have two pretty good options here. Did you ever figure out how to implement either of them?